# Is there an easy way to sort an array by month and year?

Tags: php, arrays, date, sorting

I have an array, but I need to sort it in order. Is there any easy way to do this? The array looks like this:

```
( [01/2012] => 0 [01/2013] => 4 [02/2011] => 0 [02/2012] => 0
[03/2011] => 0 [03/2012] => 0 [04/2011] => 0 [04/2012] => 0
[05/2011] => 0 [05/2012] => 0 [06/2011] => 0 [06/2012] => 0
[07/2011] => 0 [07/2012] => 0 [08/2011] => 0 [08/2012] => 1
[09/2011] => 0 [09/2012] => 5 [10/2011] => 0 [10/2012] => 3
[11/2011] => 0 [11/2012] => 7 [12/2011] => 0 [12/2012] => 2 )
```

I need it to go from furthest back to most current.

Comment: Can you build the keys differenty?  ie [201201] => 0

Comment: Why not use unix time?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using the array from an existing application, and this is what I have to work with. Ed Heal, can you convert a MM/YYYY to a Unix timestamp, then sort it by that, then convert it back to MM/YYYY?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it by converting each key to a unix timestamp, sorting the keys (ksort), then making them into month and years again.

```
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($conversions_query)){
    if($row['data']){
      $data = unserialize($row['data']);
      foreach($data as $month=>$visits){
        if($visits == ""){
          $visits = 0;
        }
        $monthstring = explode("/", $month);
        $output[strtotime($monthstring[0]."/01/".$monthstring[1])] = $visits;
      }
    }
  }

  ksort($output);

  foreach($output as $key => $val){
    $thisdate = date("m/y", $key)."<br>";
    $output[$thisdate] = $output[$key];
    unset($output[$key]);
  }

  echo "<br>SORTED OUTPUT: ";
  print_r($output);
```

Answer (score 2):

you would use the [uksort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) function.

```
uksort ( $myArray , function($keyA, $keyB){
    $monthYearA = explode('/', $keyA);
    $monthYearB = explode('/', $keyB);
    return $monthYearA[1].$monthYearA[0] >
           $monthYearB[1].$monthYearB[0] ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Comment: Instead of `mktime`, you could simply write `$arrayA[1].$arrayA[0] < $arrayB[1].$arrayB[0]`. I don't know if it is faster or not :)

Comment: Thank you for this answer, however I ended up solving it using Ed Heal's comment, I converted each key to a unix timestamp, sorted it by key (ksort), then reconverted the keys

Comment: And you like that solution better?

Comment: No I had just already done it by the time you posted your answer.